# TRIAC not triggering

Tags: microcontroller, ac, opto-isolator, triac

I am attempting to make a circuit that would allow me to control a standard CFL 13W lamp with a microcontroller. As the lamp would run on AC power, I am making use of the following circuit using a T435T-600FP TRIAC (Datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/t435t-600fp.pdf) and also using an MOC3022 optoisolator to isolate my microcontroller from the AC portion of the circuit (Datasheet: https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0019/MOC302X%20series%20201606.pdf). [image]

I cannot seem to get the TRIAC to conduct however and have been unable to figure out why. I can confirm that the optocoupler is working as expected, and suspect that the current being provided to the gate of the TRIAC should be sufficient to turn it on (I_GT = 35mA). The lamp in the circuit is a 13W CFL rated at 120V and a max current of 235mA. The CFL is not dimmable, however I simply want to turn it on and off, rather than do any dimming. What are potential problems that may be occurring? Are there any better implementations of the circuit that could be used?

Comment: The TRIAC has been placed on the neutral return path after power has been delivered to the load. Is this something that may be causing an issue?

Comment: Can you try an incandescent lamp in the 25-100W range, rather than the CFL?

Comment: `The TRIAC has been placed on the neutral return path after power has been delivered to the load` ... there is no neutral return path as seen by the lamp ... the voltage alternates symmetrically at the lamp ... so there is no such thing as `after power has been delivered to the load`

Comment: You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Swapping the MT1 and MT2 TRIAC terminals is a common error. Double-check.

Comment: The CFL lamp may need a 100 K bypass resistor so the triac behaves properly. A CFL is a very non-linear load.